# Finding Minimum in Python Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays say `x = [110, 10, 1000 ....]` and `y = ['adas', 'asdasqe', 'ae1e' ....]`

Both of these arrays are of the same length. My problem is that or printing the 10 values of `y` such that the corresponding values of `x` are the 10 largest.

In an average test case, `x` and `y` are 4000-5000 in length. So speed is of the essence. Could you tell me a way of doing this using some of the inbuilt functions of python so that the operation is as fast as possible.

Comment: strictly speaking, in python these are lists not arrays ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the ten top elements from a list of several thousands, you can try [`heapq`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html):

```
import heapq

heapq.nlargest(10, zip(x, y))
```